# How to create a TableView with dynamically added columns at runtime in JavaFX?

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview

I have a TableView that its content should be editable and actually must be persisted in the database. This TableView has some predefined columns and some other ones which will be defined at runtime. Suppose my table is going to show primary materials for some special food. These primary materials have some predefined columns (attributes) like name, price, and unit; Also these primary materials have some other attributes which are persisted in the database based on the previous user inputs like the amount of fat, protein, etc.  Note that these attributes are in the database and should be mapped to columns in the table at runtime (these columns also should be editable). So I have created the table in the fxml file and added predefined columns; Also the table model which should be declared to store table rows.
This is my table model class: (for simplicity, constructors and accessor methods are omitted)

```
public class PrimaryMaterialBean {
    private SimpleStringProperty number;
    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleStringProperty price;
    private SimpleStringProperty unit;
}
```

And TableView code:

```
<TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="170.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="816.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="121.0">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="numberColumn" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="number" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" minWidth="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" text="name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="priceColumn" minWidth="220.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="price" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="unitColumn" minWidth="90.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="unit" />
         </columns>
</TableView>
```

I know that i should declare additional dynamic columns in the corresponding controller file. Also it is knwon to me how to do add dynamic coulmns. But the actual problem is here that i do not know how to declare those columns to be editable and how to map corresponding fileds in the model class :(

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to accomplish this task and it's to create a java class at runtime. I don't know if this solution is reliable but for me, it works.